# WatchKit App Won't Load In Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, watchkit

I have been testing my WatchKit app out just fine all day.  Just now, simulator stops loading anything into the Apple Watch External Display Window.  I have tried changing Simulators, sizes, reset content and settings, quitting Simulator, cleaning the project, restarting computer, but nothing, it simply won't load.  It won't even load the spinning circle, it just sits there blank.  I get no warnings or error messages, and the Console never activates for any of my NSLogs in code.  It says attaching it and it says it is running, but nothing is there.  Like I said, everything worked fine 5 minutes ago, and nothing in code changed.

Comment: have you quit (cmd-q) xcode and re-open it, hope it will help you.

Comment: If any of the other suggestions don't help, try resetting the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem randomly and the most effective way to get it working again was to reset the simulator (ie. have the simulator delete the WatchKit App from it's internal iPhone), close it and then 'clean' the last build, rebuild and then run.

I think this beta Apple Watch Kit is still a little buggy so hopefully they will fix this, simulate the native Watch UI and add the complete list of possible interactions.

Comment: √ Resetting simulator helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache and start Xcode again.